# Merge multiple doc or rtf files into a single doc or rtf file by using php script

Tags: php, file, merge, rtf

I would like to merge multiple doc or rtf files into a single file which should be the same format of multiple files.
What I mean is that if a user selects multiple rtf template files from a list box and clicks on a button on web page, the output should be a single rtf file which combines multiple rtf template files, I should use php for this.

I haven't decided the format of template files, but it should be either rtf or doc, and also I assume that template file has some images as well.

I have spent many hours to research the library for this, but still can't find it out.

Please help me out here!! :(

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you are searching for a solution for handling RTF documents only, you can find a PHP package to merge multiple RTF documents here :

[www.rtftools.com](http://www.rtftools.com/)

Here is a short example on how to merge multiple documents together :

```
include ( 'path/to/RtfMerger.phpclass' ) ;

$merger = new RtfMerger ( 'sample1.rtf', 'sample2.rtf' ) ; // You can specify docs to be merged to the class constructor...
$merger -> Add ( 'sample3.rtf' ) ;                         // or by using the Add() method
$merger [] = 'sample4.rtf' ;                               // or by using the array access methods
$merger -> SaveTo ( 'output.rtf' ) ;                       // Will save files 'sample1' to 'sample4' into 'output.rtf'
```

This package allows you to handle documents that are bigger than the available memory.

Comment: It should be noted that this solution only works for PHP 5.4.0 and later

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a similar project and havne't managed to find any PHP (or any other open source language) libraries for manipulating MSWord files. The way I approach it is kind of complicated, but works. Here's how I would do it (assuming you have a Linux server):

Setup:

1. Install [JODConverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter) and [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/)
2. Start open office as a server (see http://www.artofsolving.com/node/10)

Approach (ie. what to do in your PHP code):

1. Convert your MSWord or RTF files into ODT format by calling JODConverter via backticks or [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)
2. Unzip each file into a temporary directory of its own
3. Read the `contents.xml` file from each unzipped document using a [DOM Parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)
4. Extract the `<office:text>` contents from each, and concatenate
5. Put this concatenated xml back into the right spot in one of the `content.xml` files
6. Re-zip the contents of that temporary directory and give it an `.odt` extension
7. Use JODConverter to convert this file back to MSWord again

As I said, it's not pretty, but it does the job.

If you're looking to go down the RTF route, this question may also help: [Concatenate RTF files in PHP (REGEX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153801/concatenate-rtf-files-in-php-regex)