# Merge two RTF documents in PHP

Tags: php, php-5.3

I've searched online in multiple places, but I can't seem to find a proper solution. I have two RTF documents that I want to merge together as follows. I have a document and a cover letter, so I want the document followed by copies of it with a cover letter before each copy, as follows:

```
Document
Cover Letter
Document
Cover Letter
Document
```

With RTF files they have markup at the beginning and end, so I can write a regex to remove the markup, which technically works fine, but the formatting can be changed in the cover letter. Also, the other problem is that the document can change - there is a list of about 10 or 15 documents that I can choose from, each of which has a different markup at the beginning of the document, so the solution that I found at [Concatenate RTF files in PHP (REGEX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153801/concatenate-rtf-files-in-php-regex) can't help in all situations.

Sadly, since I am on PHP 5.3 I can't use the solution mentioned at [Merge multiple doc or rtf files into a single doc or rtf file by using php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030335/merge-multiple-doc-or-rtf-files-into-a-single-doc-or-rtf-file-by-using-php-scrip/39820576#39820576) because it relies on PHP 5.4 or PHP 7

Comment: PHP 5.3 - upgrade

Comment: PHP 5.3 is past EOL

Comment: I didn't see a PHP version requirement on a quick read of this, but if it works, this might do it for you: https://github.com/jstewmc/rtf

Comment: @nogad I really wish I could upgrade, but this is an old project on an old server that would take way too long to upgrade

Comment: @TecBrat there is no version requirement mentioned because this library was written after 5.3 was already deprecated

Comment: upgrading php version takes seconds. your funeral when you get hacked.

Comment: I want to so badly, but it isn't my server. Although if you want to hack me, here's the info you need to know... :) Most of my projects are on a server that runs PHP 7.1